# Select the word after the dash, and not anything after the word

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have a couple of these files

```
font-normal.otf
font-bold.ttf
etc
```

I'd like to select the word after the dash, aka "normal" and just that. Not the .orf. How can I do so?

I have this, but it selects the .otf part as well.

```
[^-]+$
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your regex is that `[^-]+` matches everything (except a hyphen) until the end of the line, while you only want to match from the `-` to `.`.

Use the following regex:

```
/^.*?([^-]+)\..*$/m
```

Explanation:

- `^` - assert position at the beginning of the line
- `.*?` - match any character except newline (lazily)
- `([^-]+)` - match (and capture) one more non-hyphen characters
- `\.` - match a literal dot character (`.`)
- `.*` - match everything else until the end of the line (greedily)
- `$` - assert position at the end of the line
- `m` - multiline modifier (makes `^` and `$` match at the start and end of each line)

Code:

```
preg_match_all('/^.*?([^-]+)\..*$/m', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => normal
    [1] => bold
)
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pC8pD4)

Answer (score 1):

If you perhaps just want to keep it simple you could go with

```
 $str = file_get_contents("test.txt"); // your file names in test.txt (or pass them with string if you want...)
 $string2 = preg_match_all('/-([\w ]+)/', $str, $matches);
```

Now $matches[1] array contains all you strings between - and . (if they are only word characters; if you need numbers and other chars you can just change \w with appropriate [regex](http://www.icewarp.com/support/online_help/203030104.htm).

Use this to get 'normal' and 'bold' printed from your example.

```
echo $matches[1][0];
echo $matches[1][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be simple enough `-([^.]+)` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xO8wP6)

Edit:

- `-` match a dash
- `(` capturing group

  - `[^.]` anything that is not a literal dot
  - `+` greedy
- `)` close capturing group